Read Delta Table from Blob Endpoint with Https
I have a https blob endpoint+a SAS token and want to read a delta table in Databricks.
I tried something like that
blob_url = "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxt/xxx"
sas_token =f"sp=rl&st=xxxx-10-16T18:33:43Z&se=xxx-10-17T02:33:43Z&spr=https&sv=xx-11-02&sr=c&sig=xxxx"  # You need to replace this with the actual SAS token

# Configure the Spark session to use the SAS token
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.sas.xxx.blob.core.windows.net", sas_token)

# Define the delta table path (the path should match the structure in the container)
delta_table_path = f"{blob_url}/"

# Read the delta table into a Spark DataFrame
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)

# Show the DataFrame or do any processing you need
df.show()

But I always get UnsupportedOperationException when calling df.show()
What do I wrong?
EDIT: how traceback
UnsupportedOperationException: 
File <command-199404411414209>, line 15
     12 df = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)
     14 # Show the DataFrame
---> 15 df.show()
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1988, in SparkConnectClient._handle_rpc_error(self, rpc_error)
   1985             info = error_details_pb2.ErrorInfo()
   1986             d.Unpack(info)
-> 1988             raise convert_exception(
   1989                 info,
   1990                 status.message,
   1991                 self._fetch_enriched_error(info),
   1992                 self._display_server_stack_trace(),
   1993             ) from None
   1995     raise SparkConnectGrpcException(status.message) from None
   1996 else


Could you show the whole traceback?
